PHP get random number between 2 large decimal
function count_decimals($x){
   return  strlen(substr(strrchr($x+"", "."), 1));
}

function random($min, $max){
   echo "Min $min\n";//return as Min 4.008E-7
   echo "Max $max\n";//return as Max 4.02E-7
   die();
   $decimals = max(count_decimals($min), count_decimals($max));
   $factor = pow(10, $decimals);
   return rand($min*$factor, $max*$factor) / $factor;
}

$answer = random(0.0000004008, 0.000000402);
echo "\n" . $answer . "\n";

The value send in for $min and $max is send in as scientific notation, thus the result return as invalid decimal place, when I did an echo for the result.
How do I fix such that the function able to return the random decimal between the 2 min, max, expected response should be
between
0.0000004009 to 0.0000004019 (smaller than 0.000000402, and bigger than 0.0000004008)

Why do you need this?

This is very difficult to solve without knowing the range of the input numbers. On top of that it seems you're unaware of how floats are stored in a programming language. See the warning about floating point precision in the manual. This mean that the number you think of as 0.0000004008 is actually stored as something closer to 0.00000040079999999999998906282327147676536327...., ad infinitum. Making it virtually impossible to estimate how many number after the decimal point there are.

How about using strings as inputs? Like so: random("0.0000004008", "0.000000402");. Is that an option for you?

I'm not sure what $x+"" is supposed to do; + in PHP only operates on numbers, so it will turn the "" into 0, and $x into a number. I think it will end up doing the same as (float)$x - but then you're using the value in a string function, so it will have to convert it back to a string; so I guess it's (string)(float)$x https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

If you are using PHP 8.3 or later, there is a function built in for this purpose: Random\Randomizer::getFloat.
As you can see by the detail on that manual page, the algorithm for making sure you have an evenly distributed chance is complicated by the way floating point values work: you have to avoid picking values that will be rounded to fit in the representation.
You could attempt to implement the algorithm yourself based on the C code, which I believe is here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/random/gammasection.c
With the built-in function, though, you can simply do this:
// Convert input strings to floats
$min_float = (float)$min;
$max_float = (float)$max;

// Use the default randomizer
$randomizer = new \Random\Randomizer();

// Get your random value
$result = $randomizer->getFloat(
    $min_float, $max_float,
    // The optional third parameter lets you specify whether
    //  one or both inputs (boundaries) are possible outputs
    // Here, "open" means the boundaries are excluded
    \Random\IntervalBoundary::OpenOpen
);


@KIKOSoftware The third parameter is optional, so I left it out for simplicity. As you've pointed out, though, the question does ask for a specific boundary condition, so I've edited that in. By far the more important part of the question, and answer, is how to generate random floating point values in the first place, so I feel like "solves nothing yet" was a bit of an overstatement.

Oh, I like the \Random\IntervalBoundary::ClosedClosed! Didn't see that. Yes, this does look good (trying not to overstate it this time. ).

Closed interval boundaries will always be included in the set of selectable floats.

Yeah, sorry, I read the manual a bit more careful this time and the ClosedClosed does mean that the boundary values will be included. I'm also not sure that OpenOpen will always do what Kenny Toh wants, if it even exists. I cannot find any documentation for \Random\IntervalBoundary. However, one solution would be to still use ClosedClosed and when the boundaries are returned simply try again.

@shingo Oops, I wrote "closed" when I meant "open"; I have corrected.

@KIKOSoftware Yes, the IntervalBoundary enum doesn't seem to be documented, although the rest of the new functionality is documented very thoroughly. But OpenOpen definitely exists, and should do exactly what was asked for as far as I know. I just accidentally wrote ClosedClosed when I was editing quickly on my phone.

I have my doubts whether OpenOpen will do the correct thing, but it is clearly something one could try. There is a solution here.

@KIKOSoftware I'd be interested to hear what those doubts are.

@IMSoP It has to do with the algorithm used. As far as I can tell Open means that the boundary doesn't have to be exact. That's not the same as simply not including the boundary. But again, I'm absolutely not an expert on this γ-section algorithm, which is quite complicated.

@KIKOSoftware Hm, OK; I was basing my assumption on the examples in the manual, which definitely talk about including and excluding values. That's also what an "open interval" generally means, as far as I know. But I agree that the actually algorithm is quite complicated, so exactly how it behaves may be more subtle than that.

The significant digit of a double floating number is 15 to 16, using NumberFormatter with 17 significant digits can generate an ideal string:
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$fmt->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, '');
$fmt->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS, 17);
$minstr = $fmt->format($min, NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE);
# 0.00000040080000000

Then you can use rtrim to remove the trailing zeros:
$minstr = rtrim($minstr, '0'); # 0.0000004008


This won't work for a number like 123456.0000004008, see: https://3v4l.org/5Mste It will only work for numbers with only decimals and a limited number of them.

This is a good point, I tried using NumberFormatter to fix this defect. However, your example has 16 significant digits, so in some PHP versions it cannot generate precise results, double can guarantee 15 significant digits.

First of all, when you need to run with big number or high precision, you should BCMath functions.
But BCMath doesn't have random functions.
What you can use is multiply your number by 10^n to reach something than can be safely use with random_int for example ?

"when you need to run with big number or high precision" There is no such thing in the question.

"What you can use is multiply your number by 10^n" That's what he does already.
